# Custom filter in Gridview (Regular or Overdue)

Tags: yii2

I have a `registration_date` column where I store the date that the customer was registered in the company (example: 2015-06-12). You'll need to filter if the customer has a failed or overdue registration (if `registration_date` is longer than 365 days).

In the preview screen I can display this condition, but I need to display as a filter in **Gridview** with 2 options (Regular or Overdue).

```
[
             'attribute' => 'registration_date',
             'format' => 'raw',
             'value' => function ($model) {
                 return $model->getRegistration($model->registration_date);
             },
             'filter' => [Regular or Overdue], ????
             'contentOptions' => $contentOptions,
             'headerOptions'  => $headerOptions,
],
```

How do I make this check in model ClientSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to add a filter on the column `registration_date` which is as a `Date` type column, which should have 2 options `Regular` and `Overdue` and should filter the records based on

- `Regular`

  The option should filter out all the records that have the `registration_date` difference smaller than or equal to `365` days.
- `Overdue`

  The option should filter out all the records that have the `registration_date` difference from the current date greater than `365` days.

Your gridview column will look like below

[image]

### `GridView` Changes

If the above is correct then, first of all, add the following configuration in your gridview column configuration. we will provide an active-dropdown in the `filter` option and assign it a name `registration_status`.

**Note: I have used `select2` for the dropdown you can use the default if you do not want, and change the `$searchModel` to the exact name for the client search model that you are passing to the `filterModel` option in your gridview.**

```
[

    'filter' => \kartik\widgets\Select2::widget ( [
        'data' => $searchModel->statusOptions(),
        'model' => $searchModel ,
        'attribute' => 'registration_status' ,
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Registration Status' ,
            'class' => 'form-control' ,
            'id' => 'registration_status' ,
        ] ,
        'theme' => \kartik\widgets\Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP ,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true ,
        ] ,
    ] ) ,
    'attribute' => 'created_at' ,
    'label' => Yii::t ( 'app' , 'Registration Date' ) ,
] ,
```

#### Without `Select2`

```
[
    'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList ( $searchModel , 'registration_status' , $searchModel->statusOptions () , [ 'prompt' => 'Select Registration status' ] ) ,
    'attribute' => 'created_at' ,
    'label' => Yii::t ( 'app' , 'Registration Date' ) ,
] ,
```

### `ClientSearch` Changes

- Add the constants on top of your `ClientSearch` model.

  - `const STATUS_OVERDUE = 'overdue';`
  - `const STATUS_REGULAR = 'regular';`
- Add the function `statusOptions()` inside the `ClientSearch` model.

  ```
      public function statusOptions() {
          return [
              self::STATUS_OVERDUE => 'Overdue' ,
              self::STATUS_REGULAR => 'Regular'
          ];
      }
  ```
- Add a public property `registration_status` inside the search model.

  `public $registration_status`
- Add this field we created to the `safe` list inside the `rules()`

  function.

  ```
  function rules(){
      return [
          //other rules
          [ [.... , 'registration_status' ] , 'safe' ] ,
      ];
  }
  ```
- Then the next thing is to accomplish the SQL condition which would filter out the records, you can use MySQL functions, [`DATEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) and [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate), like `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),registration_date)>365`.

  So add the following inside the `search()` function of the search model before the last line `return $dataProvider`.

  ```
  if ( $this->registration_status === self::STATUS_OVERDUE ) {
      $query->andFilterWhere ( [ '>' , 'DATEDIFF(NOW(),registration_date)' , 365 ] );
  } else if ( $this->registration_status === self::STATUS_REGULAR ) {
      $query->andFilterWhere ( [ '<=' , 'DATEDIFF(NOW(),registration_date)' , 365 ] );
  }
  ```

Now you can filter the records based on the selected option and if you clear out the options in the drop-down it will show all of the records.

Comment: It was exactly what I needed, his response was very detailed and helped me in other similar situations as well! Thank you so much! Thank you so much!

Comment: @gugoan you are welcome dude i wont mind an upvote 

Comment: How to do without using "Select2"? I tried so but it did not work:
'filter' => ClientSearch :: statusOptions (),

Comment: i have updated the answer see **Without `Select2`** section @gugoan